# How do I implement RPC using node to an existing RabbitMQ server with an existing exchange and queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, rpc, amqp

I am having problems implementing an RPC system using node/Javascript. So far I am able to fire off a message to the correct exchange and queue which then gets is able to be consumed by a consumer, but leaves my command line hanging without a response as to whether or not the message reached the broker and/or if the process completed.

I have a working producer and consumer in python using the pika library and following the RabbitMQ tutorials but can't get it to work with node.js.

This is my working code so far:

```js
var amqp = require('amqp');

var connection = amqp.createConnection({
  host: 'amqp://username:password@xx.xx.xx.xxx:5672'
}, {
  defaultExchangeName: "myExchange"
});

var message = {

  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
}

connection.on('ready', function() {
  console.log("successful connection to host");

  connection.exchange('myExchange', {
    passive: true,
    type: 'topic'
  }, function(exchange) {
    console.log(exchange.name); //this will output to console

    connection.queue('myQueue', {
      passive: true
    }, function(queue) {
      console.log(queue.name); //this will output to console

      exchange.publish('myRoutingKey', message, {
        contentType: 'application/json'
      }, function() {
        console.log("message sent") //this does NOT output to console
      });

    });
  });
});
```

This will send the correct message and the consumer can use it to do what it needs to do.

My question is: how can I get a response back saying that Rabbit received the message?

My end game is here is to be able to loop through an array of messages and send them to my rabbit server so my consumers can process them.

Comment: Perhaps [`.subscribe()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp#queuesubscribeoptions-listener) would be useful?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/rpc_client.js and https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/rpc_server.js

Comment: BTW, we don't recommend the node library you are using

Comment: thanks @old_sound, that definitely works. the only trouble I was I needed  to bind to the queue after asserting in order to get back a message from my consumer. Still having trouble sending multiple messages on the same connection though